# c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id")) returns always 0

Tags: android

Trying to update db when listview item is clicked

other fields are fetched correctly, but _id always returns 0

int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("DESC");
  int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("AMOUNT");

long id_ = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

main:
  String[] from = new String[]{"_id", "DESC", "AMOUNT"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.list_content1,R.id.list_content2, R.id.list_content1};
        cursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.my_list_item2, c, from, to);

Comment: what do you need `long id_` for? how do you create your `Cursor`?

Comment: myDB = cont.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName",cont.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TableName
            + " (_id INT(3) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DESC VARCHAR, AMOUNT INT(3));");
    public  Cursor queueall()

    {

       return myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TableName,null);



     }

Comment: btw did you see the last param of `onItemClick` ?

Comment: yes..id=0, position=2

Comment: plus, when i add the record with   long id =myDB.insert(TableName, null, contentValues);  i can see that id!=0 and incremented correctly, problem is with fetching the id when list item is clicked

Comment: try to call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` then, and see the logcat

Comment: what is logcat . . .?

Comment: if you are not joking: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/logcat.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: key = {String@20767} "_id"
 value = {char[3]@20774} 
  0 = '_' 95
  1 = 'i' 105
  2 = 'd' 100

Comment: i debug using the device connected,step by step watching the vars..

Comment: just call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`

Comment: on the logcat? using dumpCursor? if so, your db has zeros in _id column in all the rows...

Comment: foresure db is not empty and gets uniq id per row, i can see that by the return value of the insert function command

Comment: if you dont belive `dumpCursor` method, run `sqlite3` command and see your data by yourself: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/sqlite3.html

Comment: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@33f907f8
0 {
   _id=null
   DESC=g
   AMOUNT=4
}
1 {
   _id=null
   DESC=y
   AMOUNT=5
}
<<<<<

Comment: row0: _id=null, row1: _id=null etc, all nulls

Comment: so why _id field is null ?

Comment: how do you create your table? _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: my insert function : ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("DESC", desc);
        contentValues.put("AMOUNT", amount);
        long id =myDB.insert(TableName, null, contentValues);

Comment: how do you create your table?

Comment: myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TableName
            + " (_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DESC VARCHAR, AMOUNT INT(3));");

Comment: ok then physically remove your database and run your app again

Comment: so you dont have any other practical tip..?

Comment: of course i have but it is too complex... but ok: 1) run `adb shell` 2) `sqlite3 /path/where/is/your/db` 3) type `.schema`